# still cant able to get file_get_contents alternative

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, curl, file-get-contents

Can any one help me with below url to get it as curl

```
$userData = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token='.$token.'&fields=name,id'),true);print($userData[name]).'<br/>';
```

Comment: Why what's the problem with `file_get_contents()` ?

Comment: my hosting doesnot support that function

Comment: What is the issue with using curl for this? Please post your attempt so far and explain what does not work.

Comment: Weird FB api always works with file_get_contents

Comment: here is whole code http://machineliker.com/cleaners/aa.txt

Comment: bro due to security my cpanel doesnt suport that fuction

Comment: @mpapec i also want to pass variable i cant get that

Answer (score 1):

```
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token='.$token.'&fields=name,id';
$userData = json_decode(url_get_contents($url), true);
// print($userData[name]);
print_r($userData);

function url_get_contents ($Url) {
  if (!function_exists('curl_init')){ die('CURL is not installed!'); }

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  $output = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $output;
}
```

output

```
Array
(
    [error] => Array
        (
            [message] => An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.
            [type] => OAuthException
            [code] => 2500
        )

)
```

Comment: i tried it its now working . i am not getting the expired token delete from the database

Comment: same problem bro. it delete one token even if it is exired or not i suggest you to check whole file first then try solution http://machineliker.com/file.txt

Answer (score 1):

Try this its similar to the FB PHP SDK

```
if (!function_exists('curl_init')) {
  die('Facebook needs the CURL PHP extension.');
}


//$params = array("access_token"=>$access_token,"fields"=>"name,id");
$opts = array(
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 60,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => 'facebook-php-3.1',
  );

$ch = curl_init();
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token='.$token.'&fields=name,id' ;
$opts[CURLOPT_URL] = $url;
curl_setopt_array($ch, $opts);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch) == 60) { // CURLE_SSL_CACERT    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO,
    dirname(__FILE__) . '/fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt');
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
}

if ($result === false) {
    curl_close($ch);
    die('Error in the response !! ');
}
curl_close($ch);
```

If you get some SSL issue then download `fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt` from FB SDK library and store in your server.

Comment: now getting name print

Comment: and getting one token delete every time .. even if it is active it get deleted. check whole code http://machineliker.com/cleaners/aa.txt

Comment: I did not understand what do you mean by one token delete everytime ?

Comment: i mean that i have seted run 100 token per page one execution. but it is checking only one token and deleting it from my database even if it is active it is getting delete. bro one time reffer this file and get how it works . http://machineliker.com/file.txt

Comment: ok here is some debug you can do , comment out the delete code and then echo each name `$userData[name]` and see if they are getting printed. If printed then it means the token is active. Then you can start adding the delete code.

Comment: i cant find the use full answer it is only getting one token not all 100 token

Comment: `echo "SELECT * FROM user_info ORDER BY id LIMIT $start,$per_page" ; die()` and see what you get

Comment: bro. i changed hosting where it support the function file_get_contents . thank you so much for helping